# Re-index magento via ssh / putty

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing, ssh

I have logged into my Magento instllation via `ssh/putty`, I then ran `cd public_html` to get to my root folder and am then running the following commands:

`php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute`

But nothing happens, I just get an error saying *"could not find indexer.php"*.

I have looked inside the `public_html` folder in cPanel and there is no file named `indexer.php`, only `index.php` and `index.php.sample`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this works ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't Magento-related.

Comment: in putty ssh i am doing reindexing of magento. but its showing access denied what shall i do

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146181)

Answer (score 36):

You are running this command from ROOT and `indexer.php` is located under `shell` directory. So try this commands instead:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
```

For re-indexing all indexes :

```
php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Listing all commands :

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php shell/indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
php shell/indexer.php --reindex tag_summary
```

Comment: @sandro: does this helps ?

Comment: I've come back to this answer on a regular basis for years +1+1

Answer (score 3):

Magento 1 includes an indexing script  indexer.php, which is found in the MAGENTO_ROOT/shell folder. This shell script could be used to reindex Magento using SSH.

Connect your Magento store with SSH and use cd command to go to MAGENTO_ROOT/shell

```
php indexer.php help

php indexer.php --status

php indexer.php info

php indexer.php --reindexall
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all , you have to login using ssh/putty.
Check the path using "pwd" , then go to your root folder of magento. Then "cd shell" , Once you entered in shell. check there is a file with indexer.php. run that command using ssh

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
```

Plese don't run all the command, please check in magento admin on index management than run which are showing for reindexing.