# Can't force reindex in ssh for catalog search index

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

Can't seem to reindex in back end and so thought I would give it a go in terminal

Navigated to the appropriate bits and still it won't do it.

I'm a bit of a novice at shh so wondered if someone could point me in the right direction

```
-bash-4.2$ php indexer.php --status
```

Product Attributes:                 Pending
Product Prices:                     Pending
Catalog URL Rewrites:               Pending
Product Flat Data:                  Pending
Category Flat Data:                 Pending
Category Products:                  Pending
Catalog Search Index:               Require Reindex
Stock Status:                       Pending
Tag Aggregation Data:               Pending
Algolia Search Products:            Pending
Algolia Search Categories:          Pending
Algolia Search Pages:               Pending
Algolia Search Suggestions:         Pending
Algolia Search Additional autocomplete sections: Pending
Algolia Search Queue Runner:        Pending

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_search_index
```

After running them I get this

Warning: Unknown indexer with code catalog_search_index

Any ideas where I am going wrong? would it be ok to do a force reindex for all the indexes?

I tried this solution:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

Which gave me this result:

```
Catalog Search Index index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created' in 'field list'' in /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `od...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `od...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `od...', Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Model/Queue.php(61): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('odb2sdoyhealgol...', Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Model/Resource/Engine.php(47): Algolia_Algoliasearch_Model_Queue->add('algoliasearch/o...', 'saveSettings', Array, 1)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Model/Resource/Engine.php(337): Algolia_Algoliasearch_Model_Resource_Engine->addToQueue('algoliasearch/o...', 'saveSettings', Array, 1)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Model/Resource/Engine.php(173): Algolia_Algoliasearch_Model_Resource_Engine->saveSettings(true)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(67): Algolia_Algoliasearch_Model_Resource_Engine->rebuildProducts(NULL)
#12 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(84): Algolia_Algoliasearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#13 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(455): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#18 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created' in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `odb2sdoyhealgoliasearch_queue` (`created`, `class`, `method`, `data`, `data_size`, `pid`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' in /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `od...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `od...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `od...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Model/Queue.php(61): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('odb2sdoyhealgol...', Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Model/Resource/Engine.php(47): Algolia_Algoliasearch_Model_Queue->add('algoliasearch/o...', 'saveSettings', Array, 1)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Model/Resource/Engine.php(337): Algolia_Algoliasearch_Model_Resource_Engine->addToQueue('algoliasearch/o...', 'saveSettings', Array, 1)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Model/Resource/Engine.php(173): Algolia_Algoliasearch_Model_Resource_Engine->saveSettings(true)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(67): Algolia_Algoliasearch_Model_Resource_Engine->rebuildProducts(NULL)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(84): Algolia_Algoliasearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#12 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(455): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/ashtondiscount.co.uk/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}
```

Comment: Was this resolved? I have a similar problem in Magento 1.9.3.1 Here is the error. Searches on my website produce a blank white screen. Advanced searches work fine. Catalog Search Index index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.att_color_map' in 'field list'' in "magento path"/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 "magento path"/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 "magento path"/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 "mage

Comment: I resolved my isue by making the problem field, att_color_map,  not searchable in catalog>attributes

Answer (score 0):

For the catalog search index i think the below command is what is needed to run from root directory:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

There is a good answer here about indexes:

[Re-index magento via ssh / putty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117881/re-index-magento-via-ssh-putty)

Answer (score 0):

There is no index named `catalog_search_index` in Magento 1.9. The error itself very clear that there is no such index in Magento.

The right index for catalog search would be

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

You can read this tutorial for indexing via command line

[Re-indexing Magento via command line](http://www.tutsplanet.com/re-indexing-magento-via-command-line-512/)

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: Unknown indexer with code catalog_search_index**
Please check first, Is there any **catalog_search_index** in list?

```
php shell/indexer.php info
```

If available then please please try below command

```
php -f shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_search_index
```

You are running this command from ROOT and indexer.php is located under shell directory. 
For re-indexing all indexes :

```
php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Listing all commands :

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php shell/indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
php shell/indexer.php --reindex tag_summary
```

Thank you.