# Need Indexer command for enterprise_url_rewrite for Magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, ce-1.9.1.0

Can some one help us to find indexer command for Enterprise Magento 1 for url_rewrite

Comment: you can try this module for url generate - https://github.com/elgentos/magento2-regenerate-catalog-urls

Also check this post-
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/194503/3723

Comment: Thanks , but i need Enterprise  Magento 1 command for url_rewrite

Comment: See this Post may be help full - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162169/3723

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117883/3723

Comment: Hi I need enteprise indexer for below  indexer.php --reindex catalog_url  this is used for community but for enterprise Magento 1 they have different command.